# Show $f$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E$ be an extension field of $F$. Show that if $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$ and $f\in F[X]$ is of degree $n$ with $f(\alpha) = 0$, then $f$ is irreducible.

---

For this question, it seem very trivial nut I am not sure. So, since $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$ and $f\in F[X]$ is of degree $n$ with $f(\alpha) = 0$ (this is the Kronecker’s Theorem), then we can conclude the question.  Is it right?

Also, for example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{R}$ is an algebraic in $\mathbb{Q}$,  and the polynomial is $f=x^2+2$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. This is the example that make me think this question is trivial.

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't have any argument, it just restates the hypotheses. And what is the actual statement of the "Kronecker's theorem" you refer to?

Comment: @ZevChonoles "Kronecker's theorem is my instructor's not is: Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)$ be a non-constant
polynomial in $F[X]$. Then there exists an extension field $E $of $F$ and $\alpha \in E $such that
$f(\alpha) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L/F$ be a field extension and let $\alpha\in L$. To say that $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$ is equivalent to saying that the **minimal polynomial** $p\in F[x]$ of $\alpha$ over $F$ has degree $n$. The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is the monic polynomial that generates the kernel of the evaluation map $$\mathrm{ev}:F[x]\to L,\qquad \mathrm{ev}(g)=g(\alpha)$$
The ring $F[x]$ is a PID, so the kernel $\ker(\mathrm{ev})$ is a principal ideal; the minimal polynomial is just the unique **monic** generator.

By definition, the kernel $\ker(\mathrm{ev})$ consists of precisely the polynomials in $F[x]$ that have $\alpha$ as a root; since $f(\alpha)=0$, we have that $f\in\ker(\mathrm{ev})=(p)$, and therefore $f=p\cdot g$ for some $g\in F[x]$ the minimal polynomial (since $p$ generates the ideal). But then
$$\begin{align*}
\deg(f)&=\deg(p\cdot g)\\
\deg(f)&=\deg(p)+\deg(g)\\
n&=n+\deg(g)\\
0&=\deg(g)
\end{align*}$$
so that $f=c\cdot p$ for some non-zero constant $c\in F$. Thus, because $p$ is irreducible, so is $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: if $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$, this means that if $\text{deg}(g) < n$ for $g(x) \neq 0 \in F[x]$, that $g(\alpha) \neq 0$.

Now if $f(x) = h(x)k(x)$, for $h(x),k(x) \in F[x]$ with $1 \leq \text{deg}(h),\text{deg}(k) < n$ (that is, if $f$ factors into two non-units of lesser degree, i.e., it is reducible), we have:

$f(\alpha) = h(\alpha)k(\alpha) = 0$, and since $F[x]$ is an integral domain, we must have: $h(\alpha) = 0$ or $k(\alpha) = 0$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is algebraic *of degree $n$*. Hence, $f$ is irreducible.